# Which event data format should use?

Tags: iphone, events, icalendar

I have an application that (among other features) has an event calendar. Some users need to export and import event data to their own calendars. I've found the iCalendar format, but I don't know if that's the most suitable format for me.

The format should be an extended format (as much as possible to reach the maximum number of users), particularly it must be a format that allows import/export of iPhone and Android calendars (the built in calendars).

The event data itself is very basic (name, description, start and length).

Is there any format that fits these requirements? Is there any way to make an iPhone/Android phone to import/export events in the iCalendar format?

Answer (score 0):

Yes iCalendar is the standard that you are looking for (for more information you can go to http://calconnect.org/ )

regarding exports:
iCalendar is a standard that is based on apple calendar sor iPhone is compatible with icalendar and since this is the de-facto standard for calendaring so is Android compatible.